# Display only a count of failures for Java success/fail metrics

Tags: java, prometheus, grafana, spring-micrometer, prometheus-java

Quick question regarding how to build a visual on a specific condition of a java counter in Grafana please.

Currently, I have a small piece of java code, straightforward.

```
  private String question(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        if (someCondition()) {
            Counter.builder("theCounter").tags("GOOD", "GOOD").register(meterRegistry).increment();
            return "good";
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("it is failing, we should increment failure");
            Counter.builder("theCounter").tags("FAIL", "FAIL").register(meterRegistry).increment();
            return "fail";
        }
    }
```

As you can see, it is very simple, just a "if a condition is met, increment the GOOD counter, if not, increment the FAIL counter"

I am interested in building a dashboard for the failures only.

When I query my `/prometheus` endpoint I successfully see:

```
myCounter_total{FAIL="FAIL",} 7.0
myCounter_total{GOOD="GOOD",} 3.0
```

Hence, I started using this query.

```
myCounter_total{_ws_="workspace",_ns_="namespace",_source_="source}
```

Unfortunately, this query is giving me the visual for everything, the GOOD and the FAIL. In my example, I see all 10 counters, while I just want to see the 7 failures.

I tried putting

```
myCounter_total{FAIL="FAIL",_ws_="workspace",_ns_="namespace",_source_="source}

{{FAIL}}
```

But no luck.
May I ask what did I miss please?

Answer (score 0):

Create only one counter for this case and give it a label named *status*, for example. Now, depending on whether the good or the fail condition occurs, increment your counter with a string `"GOOD"` or `"FAIL"` as a value for the status label, for example like in this pseudo code:

```
Counter myCounter =
    Counter.build().name("myCounter").help("This is my counter").labelNames("status").register();


if (someCondition()) {
    myCounter.labels("GOOD").increment();
} else {
    myCounter.labels("FAIL").increment();
}
```

Now you should be able see a query output like this:

```
myCounter_total{status="FAIL"} 7.0
myCounter_total{status="GOOD"} 3.0
```

For visualization purposes, if you'd like to see two graphs, one for good and one for bad cases, you could use something like below. This one query querying `myCounter_total` reveals its data and the Legend takes care of separating values/graphs with different status label values.

Query: `myCounter_total`

Legend: `{{status}}`

Comment: Thanks For the answer! I am currently using ```Counter``` from ```io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter``` from ```micrometer-core-1.7.1.jar```. It differs a bit from your sample. There is no usage of ```.labelNames("status")``` ```.labels("GOOD")```